# org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite seems to be firing before it should

Tags: java, selenium, testng

As I understand it, 
org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite should fire at the end of an entire suite, but it is being fired at the end of a single class.

Surely this is wrong?

I thought we had a heirarchy here - Suite > Test > Class.

Here is my testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGCustomReportListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="firefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />

        <classes>
            <class name="tests.loginTests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="tests.loginTests.AutoLogOutTest" />
            <class name="tests.loginTests.AutoLogOutWithRestApi" />
            <class name="tests.loginTests.ChangePasswordTest" />
            <class name="tests.loginTests.SwitchCustomerProjects" /> 
            <class name="tests.loginTests.ForgotPasswordResetTest" />
            <class name="tests.loginTests.EditUserNameTest" />

            <class name="tests.layersTests.EnableLayerTest" />
            <class name="tests.layersTests.EnableLayerStyleTest" />
            <class name="tests.layersTests.ChangeLayerNameTest" />
            <class name="tests.layersTests.ChangeStyleNameTest" />
            <class name="tests.layersTests.ChangeStyleColourTest" />

            <class name="tests.networks.SwitchNetworks" />

            <class name="tests.basemaps.SwitchBasemaps" />
            <class name="tests.basemaps.AddWmsLayer" />
            <class name="tests.basemaps.DeleteBasemap" />

            <class name="tests.jobs.ViewJobsLayer" />

            <class name="tests.defectsTests.ViewDefectsLayerTest" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.CreateDefectTest" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.CreateDefectNewCaller" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.CreateDefectExistingCaller" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.ViewAllDefects" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.DeleteDefectTest" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.ViewDefectDetails" />
            <class name="tests.defectsTests.EditDefectDetails" />

            <class name="tests.streetlighting.ViewStreetlightsLayer" />

        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here is the paragraph being 'wrongly' invoked:

```
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
    debug.print(thisClass + " afterSuite.");
    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " driver details " + driver.toString());
    try {
        debug.print(thisClass + " afterSuite. Final log out.");
        LogoutUtility.logout(driver, loggedInPage);
        Common.printLine();
        debug.print("\n" + thisClass + " Clean up.");
        deleteAllCookies();
        driverClose();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(thisClass+" error trying to logout. " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the report:

```
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] pageObjects.LoggedInPage                 Logged in page loaded
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] tests.loginTests.LoginTest               ASSERT: Is logged in true
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] 
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] listeners.CustomTestListener             PASSED TEST
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] listeners.CustomTestListener             tests.loginTests.LoginTest
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] crossBrowserFramework.CrossBrowserTest   afterTest. 
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] listeners.CustomTestListener             FINISH.
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] Command line test
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] crossBrowserFramework.CrossBrowserTest   afterSuite.
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] crossBrowserFramework.CrossBrowserTest   driver details FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (52c39e00-80ae-4576-a0f4-52d4a25442b5)
[15:31:56] :     [Step 2/4]    [testng] crossBrowserFramework.CrossBrowserTest   afterSuite. Final log out.
```

Ideally, I do not want to log in & out for each class. Just once for the entire suite.

Comment: Would you be able to share a simple trimmed down version of your test code that can be used to reproduce the issue ? I wasn't able to reproduce this issue using TestNG `6.14.2`. Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/24a907ac550fb9b190efffcbdd148656) for a sample

Comment: Working for me as well, @Steve can you post your code snippet here.